# How do I programatically configure my Jetty Request Handler to Handle custom HTTP methods

Tags: java, http, jetty

I Have a Jetty Handler that extends AbstractHandler, from what I can tell with online research I should be able to configure this to tell Jetty to handle verbs other than post/get. I need to configure my Jetty server to handle a "patch" request, right now jetty is returning a 405.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
package com.test.jetty.handler;

// imports

public class MyRequestHandler extends AbstractHandler {

@Override
public void handle(String path, Request request, HttpServletRequest serveletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse)
        throws IOException, ServletException {      

    String requestMethod = request.getMethod().toUpperCase();

    try {

        switch (requestMethod) {

            case "POST":
                // do post logic
                System.out.println("post");
                break;

            case "GET":
                // do get logic
                System.out.println("get");
                break;

            case "PATCH":
                // do patch logic
                System.out.println("patch");
                break;

            // so on.....

            default:
                // do default

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}